Internal package service (and/or DNS) problems during container build on TeamCity
The situation is as follows. TeamCity has its agents in Docker containers that build the apliactions. The applications are WebAPIs written in C#/.NET (the base images used are dotnet/sdk and dotnet/runtime). The build uses an official NuGet server for the dependencies and a local NuGet service, accessible only from the internal network, which has other remaining dependencies. The correct DNS to access the internal service is set on:

the "physical" machine on which TeamCity and the agents are on
the container with TeamCity
containers with TeamCity agents

During the "dotnet restore" step I get the error "NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source", the ping command call indicates that the specified domain of the internal NuGet service points to a public address rather than an internal address, indicating that the internal DNS is not being used.
It seems to me that the problem may be due to the fact that the agents are using Docker-In-Docker, and the network configuration is not passed on during the docker build, so that the internal services are not visible. I tried changing "/etc/hosts" and "/etc/resolv.conf" on the build image, the attempts failed because the changes would not stick and the network configuration would reset on subsequent Dockerfile steps.
What other way can I still enforce correct DNS addressing when building an image, or is there an alternative approach to a problem of this nature?
